# Pass array to function (C)

Tags: arrays, function, pointers, rotation

I've written a function to rotate an array,
I've checked and it works when code is in one block I.E. everything 
is coded under main(), but when I divide the code so that the rotation is done under a different function I can't get it to work (it truncates instead of rotating).
I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the array pointer.

sorry complete noob

please help:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void rotate(int *arr,int length);
int main()
 {
 // this code creates an array via input
 int length;
 int i;
 int num;
    printf("enter length of array\n");
    scanf("%d",&length);
 int arr[length];
 for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
    printf("enter number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    arr[i]=num;
 }
     // just prints original
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
    printf("original arr[%d]=%d\n",i,arr[i]);

    }


 //runs rotate function

 rotate(arr,length);

 return 0;
 }

//the rotate function inputs rotation amount and uses nested for loop to 
execute
void rotate(int *arr,int length)
{
int n;
 printf("by how many do you want to rotate array?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i;
    int j;
    int temp;
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
            temp=arr[0];
        for (i=0;i<length-1;i++)
        {

            arr[i]=arr[i+1]; 

        }
    arr[length-1]=temp;
            printf("rotated arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr[i]);
    }


    }
```

my output looks like this:

```
enter length of array
5
enter number
1
enter number
2
enter number
3
enter number
4
enter number
5
original arr[0]=1
original arr[1]=2
original arr[2]=3
original arr[3]=4
original arr[4]=5
by how many do you want to rotate array?
3
rotated arr[4] = 1
rotated arr[4] = 2
rotated arr[4] = 3

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 9s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: can you please post a sample input and output that you are getting

Comment: sure, adding to end of post, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C you need to declare the function before "main" function, or do the declaration and definition both above the main function. Also do share your error message, for help.

Also, in C language you can't really create dynamic arrays like that( i.e. taking an integer value and then defining the size of array using it "int array[integer] " is wrong of doing it, if the value of integer is being given during runtime)

Read http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/2-C-adv-data/dyn-array.html , or any other tutorial about dynamic arrays in C and how to use malloc and calloc.

Comment: Thanks, I tried declaring before main but it didn't change anything, btw I don't get an error messege, it's simply that the program doesn't work as intended.

Comment: I understand but since I input "length" before initializing arr[length] isn't it a a simple array? also I have to emphasize that this code worked until I divided it to separate functions, so as bad as it's written, that's the part of the code i'de like to fix...

Comment: I've changed the original post so that the function is declared in the header, still it doesn't work.

Comment: Ohh, seems like you are using a newer version of C, whatever it is. The problem with the logic here is, you need to have the print statement inside of the for loop block where the values of i change, and not where the value of j changes as your print statement is having i as a variable

Comment: Or just make another loop outside of the entire thing to print it

Answer (score 0):

According to me the problem is in your last print statement in rotate method which is inside the loop.

you must loop through the whole array again to print the rotated array.
like this.

```
void rotate(int *arr,int length)
{
int n;
 printf("by how many do you want to rotate array?");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 int i;
 int j;
 int temp;
for (j=0;j<n;j++)
{
        temp=arr[0];
    for (i=0;i<length-1;i++)
    {

        arr[i]=arr[i+1]; 

    }
arr[length-1]=temp;

}

for(i=0;i<length;i++){

  printf("original arr[%d]=%d\n",i,arr[i]);

  }

}
```

this will work.

And also, Always define functions at the top in c.